# SSL - Cloudflare, avast or my code?

Tags: ssl, https, web, cloudflare

I have 2 websites on 2 servers, I use the SSL cloudflare

For the first everything is ok, green padlock.
For the second, I have a grey padlock with a warning on it https://lightpics.net

> Google Chrome can see the site’s certificate, but the site uses a weak security setup (SHA-1 signatures), so your connection might not be private.
>
> Proceed with caution. These are common mistakes in websites' configurations, but that doesn't guarantee that your connection is secure.

When I disable the HTTPS verify in Avast, it become green.

Someone know why ? I have the same configuration on the both... so, it's my server, my code, avast or cloudflare ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem only came from avast : it MITM your connection and sign it again with an sha1 certificate.

To be sure, check your server with ssllabs.com

Just one more thing : https is not enough to be secure, you should redirect http to https with a 301 (permanent) redirect and use HSTS.